# Insert Multiple rows of mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

How can I insert multiple data to mysql database using php. I tried using for loop but no luck.

```
//array of input boxes
$id1=array($aa1,$aa2,$aa3,$aa4,$aa5,$aa6,$aa7);
$timeRank1=array($a3,$a6,$a9,$a12,$a15,$a18,$a21);
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
require_once("connection.php");
$a = $id1[$i];
$b = $timeRank1[$i];
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (id,swim_rank)
VALUES ('".$a."','".$b."')";
```

Comment: There is only a query, where do you execute it? use mysqli or pdo

Comment: This should help you out. Just modify the SQL as needed and binding parameters is a good idea. http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Comment: I have a multiple input boxes like
1st Name Time
2nd Name TIme
3rd Name Time
and I want to insert this data to mysql when the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just build your query in a loop and then execute it when the loop is compete

```
require_once("connection.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (id,swim_rank) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $sql .= "('".$id1[$i]."','".$timeRank1[$i]."'),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
// run your query here
```

You'll also notice I moved your include of your DB connection outside of the loop. No need to repeatedly make that call.

Also, make sure you either escape those values being inserted or use parametized queries to make your inserts to protect against SQL injections.

Comment: It can insert as may rows as your database and php memory allows for. That's gonna be a lot more than 7.

Comment: what query should I run below rtrim($sql,','); to insert this data to database. I am just new to php. I tried your code but nothing inserted.

Comment: I can't say for sure because I don't know what API you are using but it probably would be mysql_query().

Comment: If your DB connection is assigned to a variable and is `mysqli_*` and using `$con` for example, then add `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); if ( false===$sql ) { printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }` after `rtrim($sql, ',');` @user3157712 show us what your DB connection code is, minus the actual credentials, using `xxx` for each variable and place it in your question as an edit and not in a comment.

Comment: I have an error in syntax. I figured it out that the comma at the last of the string $sql is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

(**Not** looking to overstep John, **nor** to gain points)

To elaborate on [`John Conde's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21511470/): (it is easier to show here in a visual representation, instead of further comments) and as John said *"I can't say for sure because I don't know what API you are using..."*

Assuming `connection.php` contains something to the effect of:

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}
```

---

Query:

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (id,swim_rank) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $sql .= "('".$id1[$i]."','".$timeRank1[$i]."'),";
}
rtrim($sql, ',');
// run your query here

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if ( false===$sql ) { 
printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); 
}
```

Comment: The comma at the last of the string is not removed. It gives me an error in my mysql syntax near ";

Comment: You wrote under John's answer that you figured it out. @user3157712 I take it that's it working for you now?

Comment: no..I figured out why I have an error just because the comma at the end of the string is not removed. I don't know how to fix it. I tried using substr($sql,0,-1) but gives the same result.

Comment: is update multiple row in database using for loop has the same structure as what you have wrote above?

Comment: Yes, I only added a DB connection example. John did not know what type of connection you are using. @DexterAnthony

Answer (score 0):

According to mysql reference guide, here's how to insert multiple values with a single insert statement.

**INSERT INTO people (name,age)
VALUES('William',25),('Bart',15),('Mary',12);**

i.e assuming we have a table named people that has columns name and age.

Now, to translate this to PHP, a good approach is to create a query string. The following php code creates such string.

```
   $query_values = " INSERT INTO results (id,swim_rank) VALUES "; // notice space after VALUES

 if (count($id1) == count($timeRank1)) // ensure both arrays have equal number of elements
 {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($id1) - 1); $i++) // remember array index starts from
    {
        $query_values .= "({$id1[$i]},{$timeRank1[$i]})"  ;
        if ($i != (count($id1) - 1)) // you dont want a trailing comma after your last bracket
        {
            $query_values .= ",";
        }
    }
  }
```

The query produced should now be used to enter your values into your database. I hope you found this helpful. Any other queries lemme know. Cheers